# xamarin native ios change language from language page

Tags: ios, xamarin

hi I have a page that has two buttons one for English and another for Arabic, it will be the first page of the app so the user can choose any language he want.
how can i do that from A to Z because i didn't find any tutorial ?

Comment: You question is not clear, please provide more details

Comment: when the user access the app first time a page appear tell him to choose a language either english or arabic . if he click english button i will redirect him to the login page for example , with english strings , if he click arabic he will redirected to login page with arabic labels and strings, and he continue all the app with the language he chose. and in the settings of the application he can also change wherever he want the language from a dropdown menu

Comment: xamarin native ios